# Avoid names on list of plots

Tags: r, bookdown

In R Bookdown I have generated a `list` of plots (ggplots). I want to show them all, so I just write the name of the variable

`ListOfPlots`

But I get the names of the list like

```
    #
    # ListOfPlots$plot1

    (Plot 1)



    #  
    # ListOfPlots$plot2

    (Plot 2)
```

How can I avoid the text?

Comment: You could set `echo = F`, or do something like `invisible(sapply(ListOfPlots, print))`

Comment: `echo=F ` dooes not work. I'll try the other

Comment: The second actually worked. You couldd post it as an answer so that I can mark it as the correct answer @Gregor

Comment: Ah sorry - echo applies to the input commands, not the results. But the `results = "hide"` chunk option should work (assuming you don't have other text results you want printed in that chunk).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap a call in `invisible` to suppress some default return printing. For your list of plots:

```
invisible(sapply(ListOfPlots, print))
```